# Select default value in h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, seam

I am trying to show a select one menu, such that the value selected by default is the name of the city (if there is a city in the variable "item"). If there is no value, I want to show the "nothing selected".

I was trying to do something like:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{(item.city!=null)?itemTmp.city.name:''}">
    <s:selectItems .... />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

But a Parse Exception is thrown. How can I set a default value in the `h:selectOneMenu` if there is one, or "no selection" if opposite?

Comment: As a better option, why don't you use something like `Select City` at index 0, so that you don't need to handle `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the empty value, you must add a select item with an empty string or any other like "--Select City--" to the list.

```
    cityItemList.add(new SelectItem(""));  
// or cityItemList.add(new SelectItem("--Select City--"));
    cityItemList.add(new SelectItem("Greenville"));
    cityItemList.add(new SelectItem("Franklin"));
    cityItemList.add(new SelectItem("Clinton"));
    cityItemList.add(new SelectItem("Fairview"));
```